# web api support in all type of apps

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api

We want to use Web API for inter-operable purposes. i mean our web api can be exposed and used in different type of apps ( Asp.net mvc, php, android, windows store/phone and ios).

We are not using wcf and prefer web api. Will it be a good choice ? we just need http and https.

Please guide the best.

Answer (score 0):

if you only need support http protocol yes, web api is an excellent option, web api has a lot of features that can help you to build robust http services, and yes, I mean is a good choice.

be careful when you build yours web api service, use best practices, security in your service, and think in rest architecture, not only simple web services and you will have a true rest service

If you want to read more about this (to have a good base, not the final or only way to do this), see the [rest maturity model](http://martinfowler.com/articles/richardsonMaturityModel.html) and [json api](http://jsonapi.org/).

WCF is the best way when you need to support others protocols that only http.

Regards